# Cambiar fondo del XML al girar el dispositivo horizontalmente

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

resulta que estaba probando hacer de alguna forma que mi dispoitivo al ponerse horizontalmente se cambie el fondo que tenia puesto cuando esta de manera vertical, lo que venia haciendo es esto pero no se bien como hacer la parte de cambiar el fondo

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration myConfig) {

    super.onConfigurationChanged(myConfig);
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    Log.d("CHANGESCREEN", "Orientation: " + orientation);
    switch(orientation ) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            //No sabria que poner aca
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:

            //No sabria que poner aca
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo quieres cambiar el aspecto visual, con CSS3 puedes condicionar el fondo a la orientación de la pantalla (entre otras propiedades).

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
   /* Portrait styles here */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
   /* Landscape styles here */
}
```

Sacado de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858466/css-expanding-based-on-portrait-or-landscape-screen-size

Comment: Esto no funciona en una aplicación android, La pregunta del OP es relacionada a Android.